# How can i restart an instance of an App Service in Azure programmatically?

Tags: azure

I have an app service in Azure which has been scaled out to 10 instances. So when a user logs on the app i dont know which instance they will be allocated to. The issue i have is that sometimes the app freezes due to a non-responsive instance/process and i need to go through each one using process explorer and find out which it is and restart.

Is there a Health Check provided by Azure whereby I can configure so that if an instance has stopped responding to restart and email admin which instance it is ?
Also do i need to stop it , does Azure spawn another instance ?

Comment: Can you share the app code here to resolve the issue? @Traci

Comment: You can enable health check from the portal by going to your `app service >> Monitoring >> Health check >> enable and provide the path URL` on the application as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/qUqinjC.png). @Traci

Comment: You can also check the instances status over here. @Traci

Comment: @Jahnavi There is no link in your comment

Comment: Now the "path URL" thats what confuses me.. what should that be . My app is testapp.azurewebsites.net   , where do i get that path from ?  would it just be /testapp.azurewebsites.net ?

Comment: You can give path URL as `/api/health` or `/health`. @Traci

Comment: As per your ask, I suggested you to do that. Could you brief more on your issue for better understanding. @Traci

Comment: i dont get it , thats not related to my app  ? what does that path mean ? I thought it would need a path to monitor / Please clarify as i dont really get why it should be /api/health or /health ?

Comment: Yes i wil go via the health check as it is easier , but i dont know how Path is configured ?

Comment: I thought  Path is something it pings the Path every minute , so why cant it just ping testapp.azurewebsites.net  or should it ping an instance ?

Comment: You have to enable health check inside your app service itself. So do you think is there is a need to provide app URL again? @Traci

Comment: @Jahnavi I am new to all of this and am trying to learn with the help of others , so please be patient , understanding and helpful , thankyou . So is there an example on how this is done , or a link    ?

Comment: Do i need to create a Health api call in the app ?

Comment: Can you refer this [document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check.md) once? @Traci

Comment: So in reading this doco, I have an mvc .net app deployed to Azure . So do i need to have a call to my api service in the app  I dont get it , sorry ?

Comment: I will make it simple for you. Go to this URL https://resources.azure.com/ and select your subscription. And then go to your `resource group >> providers >> Microsoft Web >> sites >> your app service >> config` and there you can be able to view the health check path. @Traci

Comment: Copy the path and give it in place of a path URL. It automatically checks the app instances which you are deployed into an app service. @Traci

Comment: Thankyou , I have gone there , I have clicked on config . I can see json on the right of the page . where is the health check path ? Or is it in another menu below config ?

Comment: Also if the app is not configured for health check ... what is the name of the path ? If i look at the value HealthCheckPath in the json , it is null ?

Comment: You can be able to view the path as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/AASXdhK.png). @Traci

Comment: If it not configured, then just give /api to enable it. @Traci

Comment: So let me recap , if i give it /api , I just need to know how does it work in doing health checks ? What is the relevance of the /api if my app has not been configured for health check ? So by the sounds of it I can put anything in there , like /test123 ??

Comment: That is the default path to check the pings for a whole app service with the help of config file. @Traci

Comment: see you lost me , with config file , do i need to do settings in my web.config file?

Comment: yes web.config only. @Traci

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255254/discussion-between-jahnavi-and-traci).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As per our discussion on your requirement,*

To enable the health check of an app service instances from Portal, Go to the path `App service >> Monitoring >> Health check` as shown below.

Now provide a health probe path URL. This url has to specify to which endpoint you are trying to ping. Then it will ping to that specific endpoint at regular intervals.

If the URL returns an error http status code or fails to respond, the instance is identified as unhealthy and removed from the load balancer rotation as detailed clearly in this [blog](https://dotnetthoughts.net/azure-app-service-enable-health-check/) by @Anuraj.

If an instance remains unhealthy for one hour, it will be replaced with a new instance.

[image]

You can also verify health check by going to Metrics page from the health check blade.  This will redirect to the health status page and provide the ability to add a new alert rule too.

[image]

As given in this [article](https://appserviceblog.com/en/health-check-azure-app-services/), if you have deployed the web app from local to Azure App service then easiest way to check the health check path URL is to visit the [Resource Explorer (azure.com)](https://resources.azure.com/) link. This article provides detailed steps for accessing the web app config file.

[image]